# Do the Maranga/Kee Berries continue to activate when Harvested?

Tags: pokemon-sixth-generation

I'm considering building a Trevenant with it's Hidden Ability: [Harvest](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Harvest_%28Ability%29), so I've been looking into different berries to use to take advantage of it.

There's obviously the [Sitrus Berry](http://www.serebii.net/itemdex/sitrusberry.shtml) for the healing, but also the [Lum Berry](http://www.serebii.net/itemdex/lumberry.shtml) (combined with the move Rest for some potent healing abilities).

But then I stunble across the [Kee Berry](http://www.serebii.net/itemdex/keeberry.shtml):

> If held by a Pokémon, this Berry will increase the Pokémon's Defense stat when hit by a physical attack

and [Maranga Berry](http://www.serebii.net/itemdex/marangaberry.shtml)

> If held by a Pokémon, this Berry will increase the Pokémon's Sp. Defense stat when hit by a special attack

Which piqued my interest. But do these berries continue to activate when Harvested? I.e. will the Defense/Special defense boosts be stacked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I just tested it yesterday.

If a Trevenant holds a Kee Berry, and is hit with a physical move, the berry will activate after the move hit and if Harvest activates, the Kee Berry will be restored. Consequently, after the next physical hit, Trevenant will again have its berry activated (thus the next stat raised to now is 2 level).

I didn't test for Maranga, but there's no reason why it shouldn't work similarly.