# New Berries in Pokémon X/Y

Tags: pokemon-sixth-generation

So I was browing [pokemon-sixth-gen](/questions/tagged/pokemon-sixth-gen) and I found this question: [Do the Maranga/Kee Berries continue to activate when Harvested?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/150631/do-the-maranga-kee-berries-continue-to-activate-when-harvested)

Immediately fascinated by these berries, I went to look them up. Sure enough, they do exist!

Now, I knew about the Roseli berry (I have it on my Hydreigon right now!) but where exactly does one obtain the Kee and Maranga berries?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To start with, while I was in the process of obtaining various berries, I was directed to [a certain Reddit thread](http://www.reddit.com/r/pokemon/comments/1pmvuy/berry_guide_30_now_includes_wild_berry_trees_and/) where this [wondrous infographic with just about everything you could want to know about berries in Gen6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umSxB.jpg) was posted.

To start with, you will need the following berries (and where you can find their trees):

- **Oran** (route 5)
- **Pecha** (Camphrier City)
- **Tanga** (route 22)
- **Yache** (route 19)
- **Aspear** (route 12)
- **Leppa** (route 15)
- **Aguav** (route 6)
- **Figy** (route 21)
- **Roseli** (route 14)
- **Kasib** (route 20)
- **Mago** (route 8)
- **Iapapa** (route 10)

Now, a new aspect to berry farming in generation 6 is [mutation](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Berry_Fields#Mutation). When two different berries are planted next to each other, there's a chance that the resulting bushes will contain one or two mutations; a 'new' berry. This only works for specific combinations of berries, and the chance for mutations can be *drastically* increased by using **Surprise** or **Amaze** Mulch (although Amaze requires composting the two berries you are after).

For the following steps you are going to want a minimum of ~20 bags of Surprise Mulch (Assuming we're only growing one of each plant until the two target berries), which means mulching something quick and cheap like 3 Oran berries seven times.

1. Plant Each of the following pairs in mulched locations right next to each other:

   - Oran and Pecha (result = **Qualot**)
   - Aspear and Leppa (result = **Hondew**)
   - Aguav and Figy (result = **Grepa**)
   - Mago and Iapapa (result = **Pomeg**)
2. After we harvest those, we pair the results with our remaining starting berries. Plant the following pairs in mulched locations right next to each other:

   - Qualot and Tanga (result = **Ganlon**)
   - Hondew and Yache (result = **Liechi**)
   - Grepa and Roseli (result = **Salac**)
   - Pomeg and Kasib (result = **Petaya**)
3. After we harvest the results of step 2, we pair those off in mulched locations right next to each other:

   - Ganlon and Liechi (result = ***Kee***)
   - Salac and Petaya (result = ***Maranga***)
4. Now you just start farming berries until you feel you have a sufficient supply.

Answer (score 2):

Kee and Maranga berries are obtained by [mutation](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Berry_Fields#Mutation), which may occur when planting specific berries next to each other in the Berry fields near route 7.

For a Kee Berry, you need to plant Ganlon and Liechi berries next to each other; for a Maranga Berry you need Salac and Petaya berries.

You can use Surprise or Amaze Mulch to increase the chance of getting a mutation.

Other combinations are possible to create other mutations, but the other mutations all give berries that were also available in previous generations.

Comment: Ooh! Heh, I knew about basic mutations, but I've never really used the berry garden for anything. Now... how does one get a hold of Ganlon, Liechi, Salac and Petaya berries in X and Y...? XD

Comment: Pff, never mind, just paid attention to the link you posted. Okay, cool, gardening time!